# Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined

Tags: angular, typescript, npm

I am new to angular. I encounter this error in my `index.component.ts` file.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined

[Error screenshot attached](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xUKWA.png)

Answer (score 17):

I got this problem when upgrading from 8 to 9, thought it was a bug and even started reporting it in https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/35208, but I'm not sure it is really a bug. It might help someone having this error, though, so I'm posting here.

Short answer:

<s>For some reason</s> Because I updated Angular CLI without running the migrations (due to some very particular constraints I had), my `package.json` was like this (those dependencies were left behind):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^0.803.20",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.803.20",
    ....
```

<s>After changing it to the versions below, the problem is gone</s> The problem wouldn't happen if they were as follows:

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.900.1",
    "@angular-devkit/build-ng-packagr": "~0.900.1",
    ....
```

Keep in mind that I show the wrong/right package versions here so it's easy to identify the symptoms, but I do not recommend you updating them manually, please run the CLI migration (as explained in the ticket) and they will be updated correctly.

Comment: Went on to see the issue raised [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32215). This solution of changing the `@angular-devkit/build-angular` dependency to  `~0.900.1` worked for me as well.

Answer (score 15):

I got this problem when i was upgrading from angular 6 to angular 8, this is due to  typescript,
since my `TypeScript` version cannot be downgraded, I have overridden this method. adding below code to `index.html` will resolve issue

[GitHub Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32215)

```
<script> var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) { return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod }; }</script>
```

Comment: This saved me a ton of time, muchas gracias!

Answer (score 8):

This fixed it for me.

Added these lines to `polyfills.ts`:

```
const w: any = window
// Fix "missing __importDefault", as per https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/32215#issuecomment-543459862
w.__importDefault = (w && w.__importDefault) || function (mod) { return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod }; }
```

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem when I update my project from angular 7 to 8.
after running `ng serve` I git:

> ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.4.0 and <3.6.0
>   but 3.6.2 was found instead.

After that:

> "Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined.

I run `npm install typescript@~3.4.0` and my problem was solve.

Comment: Doesn't work
ERROR in The Angular Compiler requires TypeScript >=3.9.2 and <4.0.0 but 3.4.5 was found instead.

Comment: Thanks a lot . It worked for me for version typescript@~3.4.3

Answer (score 5):

Place following script in index.html file under the head section

```
<script>
   var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) { return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod }; }
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

The following error is due to a bad version of typescript. You have to downgrade it.

> Uncaught ReferenceError: __importDefault is not defined

Go to your `package.json` file and downgrade it to `3.5.3`:

```
"devDependencies": {
    // ...
    "typescript": "3.5.3"
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to `Index.html` and add the below script tag in the head section.

```
(Tag-Open)script(Tag-Close) var __importDefault = (this && this.__importDefault) || function (mod) { return (mod && mod.__esModule) ? mod : { "default": mod }; }(Tag-Open)script(Tag-Close)
```

**This worked for me**

Answer (score 0):

I had this issue with **angular 8**: `__importDefault is not defined`

I resolved it by downgrading **TypeScript** from **3.5.3** to **3.4.5**

Answer (score 0):

No problem is solved by adding code to ignore the problem...if the message is there is to indicate that something is not working. In my case, after updating angular (using --force) I had this same issue.

1. use npm update to see the warning errors. In my case I had this results:

   npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies
   yourself.

   npm WARN @angular-devkit/build-angular@0.803.29 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.1 < 3.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yoursenpm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.3.29 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^8.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

   npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@8.3.29 requires a peer of typescript@>=3.4 < 3.6 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
   npm WARN codelyzer@5.2.2 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@>=2.3.1 <10.0.0 || >9.0.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.1.0-beta <10.0.0 || >9.2.0-beta <10.0.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
   installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.

   npm WARN karma-jasmine-html-reporter@1.5.4 requires a peer of jasmine-core@>=3.5 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
2. Now, knowing the outdated packages, try to update the required packages in the terminal using CLI:

   ng update @angular-devkit/build-angular

   ng update @ngtools

   ng update codelyzer

   ng update jasmine-core

And problem solved. Next time guys, just remember not to copy-paste code without thinking, but try to find the real source of the problems...that's why none of the other answers here is gonna work for you. Every problem is different.